# Semantic zooming on Canvas using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

I'm having trouble implementing a semantic zoom on Canvas. I tried to replicate this example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3681006) but some of the relevant functions have been changed as d3 transitioned to v4, and I have a hunch that the problem is probably how I'm rescaling.

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kdqpxvff/

```
var canvas = d3.select("#mainCanvas"),
mainContext = canvas.node().getContext("2d"),
width = canvas.property("width"),
height = canvas.property("height")

var zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 400])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

var canvasScaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([-100,500])
.range([0, 800]);

var canvasScaleY= d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([-150,200])
.range([0, 500]);

var randomX = d3.randomUniform(-100,500),
randomY = d3.randomUniform(-150,200);

var data = d3.range(2000).map(function() {
    return [randomX(),randomY()];
});

function zoomed() {
    mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    var transform = d3.zoomTransform(this);
    canvasScaleX=transform.rescaleX(canvasScaleX);
    canvasScaleY=transform.rescaleY(canvasScaleY);
    draw();
}

canvas.call(zoom);

function draw(){
    data.forEach(function(each,something){
        mainContext.beginPath();
        mainContext.fillRect(canvasScaleX(each[0]), canvasScaleY(each[1]),3,3);
        mainContext.fill();
    });
}

draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem, the error seems to be induced by my linear scales namely:

```
var canvasScaleX = d3.scaleLinear().domain([-100,500]).range([0, 800]);

var canvasScaleY= d3.scaleLinear().domain([-150,200]).range([0, 500]);
```

I'm still not sure why these were tripping my code up, but I will continue to work on it and post an update in case I find out. In the meanwhile here is the solution I found — https://jsfiddle.net/4ay21wk1/